# FlowType - Repeating Declaration Of Complex Objects

Tags: javascript, flowtype, variable-types

Excuse the newbie question, I'm struggling through understanding / integrating flowType into my react/redux project.

My question is, do we have to repeat ourselves (with declaring types), when we declare properties which contain already declared (elsewhere) properties ?

To elaborate, I have Higher-Order functions, which filter through props so that relevant `action-creator` function is called with relevant arguments. Here is a HO function, which takes 4 objects as arguments.

Just focusing on the first one: `envProps`. its code is as follows:

```
type envProps = {
    eCCurSelectedEle : string,
    renderTab : string,
    target : {
        pos : string,
        // collection is an object containing dynamically
        // inserted template objects with sub-objects. How would
        // I handle this? Do I have to break-down each object
        // property in this 'collection' & declare its inner
        // prop types and so on?
        collection : Object
    },
    targetPos : {
        h : number,
        w : number,
        pageX : number,
        pageY : number
    },
    toolbarCtrl : string
};

// just focusing on the first prop: envProps
export const svgMouseDownHandler = ( envProps : envProps,
                                                svgProps,
                                                target,
                                                prevSelectedTarget ) => {
...
```

Do I have to declare each property-type within each argument, even if that property has been declared somewhere else?
How would I deal with dynamic objects?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can split out each type like this, and then you can use it separately as needed.

```
type Target = {                                                                  
  pos: string,                                                                   
  // collection is an object containing dynamically                              
  // inserted template objects with sub-objects. How would                       
  // I handle this? Do I have to break-down each object                          
  // property in this 'collection' & declare its inner                           
  // prop types and so on?                                                       
  collection: Object                                                             
};                                                                               

type TargetPos = {                                                               
  h: number,                                                                     
  w: number,                                                                     
  pagex: number,                                                                 
  pageY: number                                                                  
};                                                                               

type envProps = {                                                                
  eCCurSelectedEle: string,                                                      
  renderTab: string,                                                             
  target: Target,                                                                
  targetPos: TargetPos,                                                          
  toolbarCtrl: string                                                            
};
```

As for dynamic objects, Flow can understand some dynamic patterns but what you have asked is very broad. I think it would be best to post a separate question for that with a specific example.